# Looping over items in a List to return Dictionary Values Python

Tags: python, list, for-loop, dictionary, printing

I have the following basically working but am struggling with the final printing. It's calling on data held in a text file with entries such as:

```
I,ngaju
dance,juka-pinyi
```

The code reads user input and compares it to a dictionary populated by the text file to translate from English to Aboriginal. So far so good, but when I enter more than one word of user input, it's only returning the last word in Aboriginal. So 'I dance' only prints 'juka-pinyi'. What am I doing wrong?!

```
dictionary = {}

for line in open('dictionary.txt'):
  english, aboriginal = line.strip().split(',')
  dictionary[english] = aboriginal

word = input('English: ').lower().split()

while word != []:
  for item in word:
    if item in dictionary:
     print (dictionary[item])
      word = input('English: ').lower().split()
```

EDIT:

Thanks for the comments. It's now working with the lowercase issue resolved and the indentation, but is returning words on separate lines. Just need to research how to get it to print them on the same line!

```
dictionary = {}
for line in open('dictionary.txt'):
  english, aboriginal = line.strip().split(',')
  dictionary[english.lower()] = aboriginal

word = input('English: ').lower().split()

while word != []:
  for item in word:
    if item in dictionary:
      print (dictionary[item])
  word = input('English: ').lower().split()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your dictionary is like this:

```
{'I':'ngaju','dance':'juka-pinyi'}
```

and your input is **'I dance'** but you are converting each word to lowercase using this:

```
word = input('English: ').lower().split()
```

which makes the input as **'i dance'**. Thus it only find **'dance'** in dictionary and gets translated. You need either to populate dictionary with only lowercase letters using this:

```
dictionary[english.lower()] = aboriginal
```

instead of:

```
dictionary[english] = aboriginal
```

or you need to take input without converting it to lowercase using this:

```
word = input('English: ').split()
```

instead of:

```
word = input('English: ').lower().split()
```

Answer (score 2):

I dance - obviously returns juka-pinyi because 'i' is not in dictionary and you are lower casing the user input :)

Otherwise, code seems fine. I am assuming it is a typo that the last line is incorrectly indented.

Answer (score 2):

The dictionary excerpt you've included implies that the entries are case-sensitive.  The call to str.lower() will prevent the word "I" from ever being matched, since it gets flattened to lower case after the user enters it.  If your intent is to force everything to be lower case, I'd recommend you change the dictionary initialization code to something like this:

```
for line in open('dictionary.txt'):
  english, aboriginal = [i.lower() for i in line.strip().split(',')]
  dictionary[english] = aboriginal
```